# Executar um código antes de tudo

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

Bom dia..
Quando eu aperto qualquer MENU, BOTÃO, link, etc tudo funciona corretamente e perfeitamente, contudo, tem horas que o código a ser executado demora, as vezes um pouco, as vezes mais que um pouco. Isso me incomoda muito pois não sei se cliquei, ai clico novamente. Essa sensação dever ser a mesma de um usuário. Então o que gostaria de fazer é fazer uma ampulheta aparecer ANTES DE TUDO.
A ampulheta/aguarde eu já sei fazer. Utilizo essa maneira: 
https://github.com/raphaelfabeni/css-loader

Em alguns botoes no onclick que chama uma função eu "disparo" o APARECIMENTO DA AMPULHETA/AGUARDE, e ao final da execução da função eu "TIRO" o AMPULHETA/AGUARDE. Com isso se estou processando algo no servidor ou uma tarefa mais demorada, eu mostro ao usuario que algo esta acontecendo... e quando a tarefa é terminada a ampulheta some e o usuário sabe que pode prosseguir.
O que eu gostaria de aprender afazer é quando eu clicar em um item do menu exe:

```
<li><a href='especialidade_01.php'>Especialidades</a></li>");
```

essa pagina desse item do menu já vir com a AMPULHETA/AGUARDE "carregada" e ao termino do "carregamento" da página "TIRAR" a "AMPULHETA/AGUARDE".
Tem horas que clico em um item do menu e a página demora a aparecer.. muito chato mesmo.
Desculpem as palavras/terminologia que usei para relatar mas realmente não sei ainda como chamar/descrever essa situação adquadamente por falta de experiencia..

Comment: Boa tarde @LeoCaracciolo .. Primeiro quero agradecer sua atenção :).. Vou dar uma olhada. :) obrigado

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo Ola.. cara li o link que tu passou.. mas pelo que eu entendi ele é para mostrar APÓS o carregamento.. não é isso?? Abraços.

Answer (score 0):

no `<body>`você pode colocar um `onload` com essa função

```
<body onload="nomeDaFuncao()">
```

Serve?

Comment: Constamilam Ola.. Obrigado por responder :) .  Cara o código é ate chamado, mas NÃO na HORA do click do menu.  Se eu deixar o browser parado na tela principal onde tem os menus e depois de uns minutos clicar no menu que quero, ele demora a carrega ( fica rodando uma load na aba do browse durante um tempo, DEPOIS é que chama a função que esta no onload.

Comment: Você pode chamar no onclick do menu, assim quando o usuário clicar na opção do menu vai aparecer que está carregando e quando carregar a outra página ja vai ter desaparecido

Comment: Constamilam.. foi exatamente isso que estava pensando aqui..estou tentando fazer um javascript para ao clicar qualquer menu chamar o load :)